# decodeURIComponent is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use this function in componentWillMount() of my React.js component. But the browser is saying window.decodeURIComponent(...) is not a function, which I don't understand. Can anyone tell me how to get it work? Thanks

```
export const getUrlQuery = window => {
  let queryDict = {}
  if (window.location.search) {
    window.location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach((item) => {
      let s = item.split("=")
      let key = s[0]
      let value = s[1] && window.decodeURIComponent(s[1])
      (queryDict[key] = queryDict[key] || []).push(value)
    })
  }
  return queryDict
}
```

Comment: are you passing window into your getUrlQuery function at all?

Comment: yes it is passed down, or it should report undefined on window.location.search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting error, it turns out that the `let value = ..` line is parsed as

```
let value = s[1] && window.decodeURIComponent(s[1])(queryDict[key] = queryDict[key] || []) ..
```

In other words, you're applying the parenthesized expression to the result of `window.decodeURIComponent(s[1])`, which is string and not a function. You can fix it with an explicit semicolon (which is not a bad idea in general):

```
let value = s[1] && window.decodeURIComponent(s[1]);
```

UPD: Seeing what the code is doing, you might be interested in the [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) npm package.

Comment: This is why we always terminate every statement with semicolon, kids.

Answer (score 0):

After I removed this part of the code, things work.

```
(queryDict[key] = queryDict[key] || [])
```

Looks like this grammar error is causing the yelling instead of decodeURIComponent()